# Stripe SCA webhooks return 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate the new Stripe SCA checkout in my ruby on rails application. I followed the instructions bnwpro wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884800/new-stripe-sca-checkout-flow-in-rails) to get started. At this point I get redirected to the Stripe payment page and back to my application after payment is complete.

The issue i'm struggling with is the webhooks, when looking at the Stripe CLI i keep getting an 401...

```
2020-03-15 17:22:47   --> charge.succeeded [evt_1GMzEgI1EtCroaCdHmRufFBK]
2020-03-15 17:22:47   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_1GMzEgI1EtCroaCdWzbnaczh]
2020-03-15 17:22:47  <--  [401] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe-webhooks [evt_1GMzEgI1EtCroaCdHmRufFBK]
2020-03-15 17:22:47  <--  [401] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe-webhooks [evt_1GMzEgI1EtCroaCdWzbnaczh]
2020-03-15 17:22:47   --> payment_method.attached [evt_1GMzEgI1EtCroaCd4quSj3kR]
2020-03-15 17:22:47  <--  [401] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe-webhooks [evt_1GMzEgI1EtCroaCd4quSj3kR]
2020-03-15 17:22:47   --> customer.created [evt_1GMzEgI1EtCroaCdHpEmU1Ai]
2020-03-15 17:22:47  <--  [401] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe-webhooks [evt_1GMzEgI1EtCroaCdHpEmU1Ai]
2020-03-15 17:22:47   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1GMzEhI1EtCroaCdf1x9gUUR]
2020-03-15 17:22:47  <--  [401] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe-webhooks [evt_1GMzEhI1EtCroaCdf1x9gUUR]
```

My log shows me:

```
Started POST "/stripe-webhooks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-15 17:22:24 +0100
Processing by CheckoutsController#stripe_webhook as XML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"evt_1GMzEJI1EtCroaCdrKXWf4gV", "object"=>"event", "api_version"=>"2018-02-28", "created"=>1584289343, "data"=>{"object"=>{"id"=>"pi_1GMzEJI1EtCroaCdY3wKhKNG", "object"=>"payment_intent", "allowed_source_types"=>["card"], "amount"=>15000, "amount_capturable"=>0, "amount_received"=>0, "application"=>nil, "application_fee_amount"=>nil, "canceled_at"=>nil, "cancellation_reason"=>nil, "capture_method"=>"automatic", "charges"=>{"object"=>"list", "data"=>[], "has_more"=>false, "total_count"=>0, "url"=>"/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1GMzEJI1EtCroaCdY3wKhKNG"}, "client_secret"=>"pi_1GMzEJI1EtCroaCdY3wKhKNG_secret_6djH08QObem66sqpCYdB8P9A4", "confirmation_method"=>"automatic", "created"=>1584289343, "currency"=>"usd", "customer"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "invoice"=>nil, "last_payment_error"=>nil, "livemode"=>false, "metadata"=>{}, "next_action"=>nil, "next_source_action"=>nil, "on_behalf_of"=>nil, "payment_method"=>nil, "payment_method_options"=>{"card"=>{"installments"=>nil, "request_three_d_secure"=>"automatic"}}, "payment_method_types"=>["card"], "receipt_email"=>nil, "review"=>nil, "setup_future_usage"=>nil, "shipping"=>nil, "source"=>nil, "statement_descriptor"=>nil, "statement_descriptor_suffix"=>nil, "status"=>"requires_source", "transfer_data"=>nil, "transfer_group"=>nil}}, "livemode"=>false, "pending_webhooks"=>2, "request"=>{"id"=>"req_iRi1XVG06fMcld", "idempotency_key"=>nil}, "type"=>"payment_intent.created", "checkout"=>{"id"=>"evt_1GMzEJI1EtCroaCdrKXWf4gV", "object"=>"event", "api_version"=>"2018-02-28", "created"=>1584289343, "data"=>{"object"=>{"id"=>"pi_1GMzEJI1EtCroaCdY3wKhKNG", "object"=>"payment_intent", "allowed_source_types"=>["card"], "amount"=>15000, "amount_capturable"=>0, "amount_received"=>0, "application"=>nil, "application_fee_amount"=>nil, "canceled_at"=>nil, "cancellation_reason"=>nil, "capture_method"=>"automatic", "charges"=>{"object"=>"list", "data"=>[], "has_more"=>false, "total_count"=>0, "url"=>"/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1GMzEJI1EtCroaCdY3wKhKNG"}, "client_secret"=>"pi_1GMzEJI1EtCroaCdY3wKhKNG_secret_6djH08QObem66sqpCYdB8P9A4", "confirmation_method"=>"automatic", "created"=>1584289343, "currency"=>"usd", "customer"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "invoice"=>nil, "last_payment_error"=>nil, "livemode"=>false, "metadata"=>{}, "next_action"=>nil, "next_source_action"=>nil, "on_behalf_of"=>nil, "payment_method"=>nil, "payment_method_options"=>{"card"=>{"installments"=>nil, "request_three_d_secure"=>"automatic"}}, "payment_method_types"=>["card"], "receipt_email"=>nil, "review"=>nil, "setup_future_usage"=>nil, "shipping"=>nil, "source"=>nil, "statement_descriptor"=>nil, "statement_descriptor_suffix"=>nil, "status"=>"requires_source", "transfer_data"=>nil, "transfer_group"=>nil}}, "livemode"=>false, "pending_webhooks"=>2, "request"=>{"id"=>"req_iRi1XVG06fMcld", "idempotency_key"=>nil}, "type"=>"payment_intent.created"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Resulting in the webhoock not being triggerd and the code not being executed.

Who can point me in the right direction? Google and Stack searches have failed me this time...

**Edit 1:**
app > controllers > checkouts_controller.rb

```
class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController
  require 'stripe'
  before_action :setplans
  skip_before_action :checkStatus
  protect_from_forgery except: :stripe_webhook


  Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_...'
  endpoint_secret = "whsec_..."



  def index
  end

  def new
    Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_...'

    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        name: @product.title,
        amount: @product.price,
        currency: 'usd',
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      "metadata": {days: "#{@product.days}"},
      success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cancel',
    )
    @stripe_session = session
  end

  def success
  ### the Stripe {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} will be available in params[:session_id]
    if params[:session_id]
      flash[:success] = "Thank you! Your license has been updated!"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Session expired error..."
      redirect_to checkouts_path
    end
  end

  def cancel
    redirect_to checkouts_path
  end

  def stripe_webhook
    stripe_response = StripeWebhooks.subscription_events(request)
  end


  private

  def setplans
    @licenseplans = Product.where(active: true)
  end


end
```

The stripe_webhook lives under app > services > stripe_webhooks.rb

```
class StripeWebhooks
  require 'stripe'
  STRIPE_API_KEY = "sk_test_..."

  def self.subscription_events(request)
    new(request).subscription_lifecycle_events
  end

  def initialize(request)
    @webhook_request = request
  end

  def subscription_lifecycle_events
    authorize_webhook

    case event.type
    when 'customer.created'
      handle_customer_created
    when 'checkout.session.completed'
      handle_checkout_session_completed
    when # etc.
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :webhook_request, :event

  def handle_customer_created(event)
    ## custom actions
  end

  def handle_checkout_session_completed(event)
    ## custom actions
  end

  def authorize_webhook
    Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_...'

    endpoint_secret = "whsec_..."

    payload = webhook_request.body.read
    sig_header = webhook_request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    @event = nil

    begin
      @event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
      )
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      puts e.message
    rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
      puts e.message
    end
  end
end
```

config > routes.rb

```
...
  # Stripe SCA checkout routes
  get 'success', to: 'checkouts#success'
  get 'cancel', to: 'checkouts#cancel'
  resources :checkouts
  post '/stripe-webhooks', to: 'checkouts#stripe_webhook'
...
```

There are a number of hardcoded keys for the moment which need to be moved and stored in a safer place after I get this auth error fixed

Comment: That 401 is coming from your local server. Can you share the code for your CheckoutsController?

Comment: @w1zeman1p updated with the checkouts_controller and stripe_webhooks.  Somewhere a key is invalid or i was thinking about the "sig_header = webhook_request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']" part? . Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like your server is expecting authentication for the webhook POST request, which is why it's returning a 401 - so you need to make sure that route doesn't require authentication.

Comment: @floatingLomas i had already tried with a skip_before_action :authenticate_user! only for the webhook... (This returned a 500)  I'm using Devise in my application

Comment: Can you share the 500 error when you skip the before action for authenticate_user! ? I think @floatingLomas is right, here. We need to skip both CSRF and any default authentication that's happening.

Comment: Thank you both for your help and pointing me in the right direction... I've put my updated controller below which returns all 200's now ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've moved the webhook from the service to the controller for the moment and added the skip_before_filter again BUT moved the endpoint_secret key to the webhook and get beautiful 200's now!

Now I just need to extract the metadata part and get working on the appropriate action after a successful payment...

The updated controller:

```
class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController
  require 'stripe'
  before_action :setplans
  skip_before_action :checkStatus
  protect_from_forgery except: :stripe_webhook
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:stripe_webhook]


  Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_...'


  def index
  end

  def new
    Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_...'

    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        name: @product.title,
        amount: @product.price,
        currency: 'usd',
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      metadata: {days: :"#{@product.days.to_s}"},
      success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cancel',
    )
    @stripe_session = session
  end

  def success
  ### the Stripe {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} will be available in params[:session_id]
    if params[:session_id]
      flash[:success] = "Thank you! Your license has been updated!"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Session expired error..."
      redirect_to checkouts_path
    end
  end

  def cancel
    redirect_to checkouts_path
  end

  def stripe_webhook
    sig_header = request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    endpoint_secret = "whsec_..."

    begin
      event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(request.body.read, sig_header, endpoint_secret)
    rescue JSON::ParserError
      return head :bad_request
    rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError
      return head :bad_request
    end

    webhook_checkout_session_completed(event) if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed'

    head :ok
  end


  private

  def setplans
    @licenseplans = Product.where(active: true)
  end

  def webhook_checkout_session_completed(event)
    object = event['data']['object']

  end

end
```